# Subquery returned more than 1 value in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-update

I have a small query when I run it, I am getting the errors. Please help me.
Query:

```
update MozendaData set [Sub Device]=
(select [Sub Device] from oldMozendaData 
     where MozendaData.[Product Details]=oldMozendaData.[Product Details]) 
where UserID ='APAC\gsvivekanand'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
UPDATE m
SET m.[Sub Device] = o.[Sub Device] 
FROM MozendaData AS m
INNER JOIN oldMozendaData AS o ON m.[Product Details] = o.[Product Details]
WHERE m.UserID ='APAC\gsvivekanand';
```